# maven2 use libs in a specific folder during compilation

Tags: maven-2, jar, build-process

In my project structure there is a folder called /libs which contains all necessary libraries, that my project need during compilation. Is it possible that I told maven2 during the process of compilation to use these libraries instead of dependencies or smth. else?

So I call mvn compile war:war and after that my .war contains the libraries out of the /libs folder.

BR,
mybecks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for [System Dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies) like

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>foo</groupId>
      <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/foo-bar-2.0.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

System dependencies will not be copied into the war file - maybe you can achiev this by putting them into `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib` directory instead of `${project.basedir}/libs`.

*DISCLAIMER: I just tried to answer the question and do not recommend the solution for all dependencies.*

Comment: when i copy them to the /WEB-INF/lib folder, then I don't need the dependency anymore or?

Comment: @mybecks Maven will use the dependencies to generate the classpath which you need to compile. Maven will not fetch these jars without dependency definition - thus you will need them. It seems that you are trying to use maven on a quite 'conventional' project setup. As maven works a lot by _convention over configuration_ (e.g. [directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)) it will be hard to achieve what you might want.